# Workaround for FloatingActionButton inactive above TextField or TextArea whilst editing

Tags: codenameone

Since a [FloatingActionButton is inactive above a TextArea or TextField whilst editing](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2118) I tried to work around this issue by placing the TextField and the FloatingActionButton into a Container styled as a TextField. But this lays out in a very strange way - see the second TextField in the following example:

```
public class FormSeveralInputFields extends Form {
    public FormSeveralInputFields() {
        super("FormSeveralInputFields", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setScrollableX(false);
        setScrollableY(true);
        Container containerFields = new Container(new GridBagLayout());
        Style styleContainerFields = containerFields.getAllStyles();
        styleContainerFields.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        styleContainerFields.setPaddingUnit(
                Style.UNIT_TYPE_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE,
                Style.UNIT_TYPE_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE,
                Style.UNIT_TYPE_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE,
                Style.UNIT_TYPE_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE);
        getContentPane().add(containerFields);
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = x;
            gbc.gridy = y;
            containerFields.add(gbc, new Label("TextField1"));
        }
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = ++x;
            gbc.gridy = y;
            TextField textField = new TextField(10);
            Log.p(textField.getStyle().getBorder().getClass().getSimpleName());
            FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(2.0f);
            FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_CLEAR);
            Container container = floatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(textField, Component.RIGHT, Component.CENTER);
            floatingActionButton.addActionListener((aActionEvent) -> textField.setText(""));
            containerFields.add(gbc, container);
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = x;
            gbc.gridy = y;
            containerFields.add(gbc, new Label("TextField1"));
        }
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = ++x;
            gbc.gridy = y;
            TextField textField = new TextField(10);
            FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(2.0f);
            FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_CLEAR);
            floatingActionButton.addActionListener((aActionEvent) -> textField.setText(""));
            BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
            Container container = new Container(borderLayout);
            container.setUIID(textField.getUIID());
            textField.setUIID("");
            container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textField);
            container.add(BorderLayout.EAST, floatingActionButton);
            containerFields.add(gbc, container);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: This affects the display in the simulator and on an iPhone SE.

By the way: Emojis are displayed in a different size during the editing process.

Answer (score 0):

We recently added `ClearableTextField` to provide this sort of functionality just use:

```
TextField tf = ...;
myContainer.add(ClearableTextField.wrap(tf));
```

Comment: ... and it makes the text fields "fatter". I wonder how I can avoid that.

Comment: I have looked into the source code of the ClearableTextField # wrap method and noticed that TextField # stopEditing and TextField # startEditingAsync are called. Why is it desirable to do that - it seems to work without those and the keyboard does not bounce then?

Comment: I'll change it so it will work with text area too, didn't see so much of a use case for that but if you want it that's one line of code to change.  It's "fatter" because of the icon size I'll add `wrap(TextArea tf, float iconSize)` which will allow you to specify the size of the clear icon in millimeters. The stop/start is healthier to do that in terms of portability, you can't test your app in all device/keyboard combinations and there might be hidden race conditions so this is a safer approach.

Comment: I'm afraid that the ClearableTextField approach won't work well with a TextArea because this shrinks the TextArea's with on its full height. That is what I meant with that it is no solution for TextArea.
Wouldn't it be much nicer to have the "native" component pass through the pointer events?
I feel that FloatingActionButton should work regardless of whether editing is in progress or not.

Comment: Editing is a special case. Even the native iOS clear code in Safari doesn't overlap the edit area because then you wouldn't be able to distinguish between clear and a copy/paste style finger edit.  I don't get your point about the text area.

Comment: Putting the button at one side of a TextArea makes no sense because the space taken by the button would extend to the full side of the TextArea and thus take too much screen estate.

Comment: Thinking about scrollable forms containing TextField and TextArea instances - if such a form contained a FloatingActionButton bound to the content pane that would not work well, right?

Comment: I can't think of a UI like this with text area, what does Apple do in these cases? 
A scrollable UI with text areas doesn't have action buttons since they will impact the functionality. This isn't a platform limitation it's a conceptual limitation and bad design if you do that in native too. In fact Google specifically doesn't use a FAB in the compose window because the keyboard will make the UI look awful! Fab has a special mode to exist within the title area which is more appropriate in such cases